# Gap between two UItableview cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app i am using tableview with cells having images coming from server. I want to give some space or gap or line between two cells. if i use

```
[tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

I am able to separate the cells but not the image view. I also want to give space or gap or line between the cell.imageviews.

[image: Please see the screenshot]

I want to give gap between the cell imageviews above

Comment: increase your tableview cell height.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use below code:

```
 yourTableView.separatorInset=UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

and if you want a custom separator, then you can use below code:

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 2)];/// change size as you need.
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];// you can also put image here
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way you can do very easily from story board also
 .[image]

Answer (score 0):

My question will be, how do you add the image to your table cell...from what i can tell your images are not in the right place, it's like you're adding the image to the table row not in the cell that spouse to be on that row, your problem is not in the separator...because its starts after your image...hope you understood my point, but who knows...may be i'm wrong...some code will be usefull